# How to set jQuery variable value in static dropdown if match exist in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue with changing the dropdown value

[image]

here is an static dropdown contains various occupation

my jQuery variable value is suppose "Business".

i need to compare it with the dropdown value, if it exists in dropdown then make the attribute **["selected"="selected"]**

**How it is Possible**

Comment: did you wants to select on page load ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use below code -

```
$("#id-of-drop-down").val("Business");
```

If the value Business exists their then it will get selected.

And if the value and text are different in the drop down and you want to select if the value matched with the text, then you can use below code -

```
var selectedText="Business";
$('#id-of-drop-down option').map(function () {
if ($(this).text() == selectedText) return this;
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var jQvar = "Business";
$('select').find('option').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('value') == jQvar) {
    $(this).attr('selected',true);
  }

});
```

Here is the working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/77kgqc62/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

***A Working Example***

```js
var JQoption = "Option 3";

$(window).on("load", function () {
    $('#select2 option').map(function () {
      if ($(this).text() == JQoption) return this;
    }).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
});
```

```css
#select2{
 width:300px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select id="select2" class="select2">
  <option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```